# Как вызвать метод контроллера из view не создавая маршрута на Laravel?

Tags: laravel

как можно переходить их вьюшки в нужный метод при этом не создавая маршрут на laravel?

Ссылка:

```
    <td><a  href="/admin_panel/users_card/{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Просмотр</a></td>
```

Маршрут:

```
 Route::get('/verified/{id}',[\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController::class, 'verified',]);
```

Контроллер

```
  public function verified($id){
  //$users=Admin::verified($id);
    // return redirect()->to(route('users'));
}
```

Comment: Что значит "переходить из вьюшки в нужный метод"? Ссылку привели с одним роутом, пример роута и контроллера - для другого роута

Comment: А может лучше не надо?)

Answer (score 0):

Не лучшая практика конечно так делать, но если очень нужно, то объявите ваш метод как public static function..в этом случае, можете вызвать данный метод из вьюшки.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, просто интересно было, как это можно реализовать